# How to show 3 fields in a single textbox in an asp.net GridView

Tags: asp.net

I need 3 Fields. Two fields in first line last fields in another line. My code is below.

Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")+" - "+ Eval("Lastname")+""+ Eval("Designation")%>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")+" - "+ Eval("Lastname")+"\n" + Eval("Lastname")%>' 
The Above code working